# Question on nomenclature of ... mappings?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, lie-algebras, stereographic-projections

I would like to understand "in english", what this sentence is saying here:

[image]

I understand what $R^3$ means, but I am not sure I understand the rest...

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The image is from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02565).

Comment: This rather depends on what $\Omega$ denotes.

Comment: Hi @LordSharktheUnknown, thanks, I updated the question. Does that help?

Comment: It's not much better. Your update doesn't really adress Lord Shark the Unknown's question : we still have no idea what $\Omega$ is. And personally I'm really puzzled by the fact that the codomain of $\Pi_c$ and the domain of $\Pi_c$ don't match. Perhaps you could give a reference or a link for the source?

Comment: Hi @ArnaudD., yes, I am confused as well. Anyway, here is the direct link: (https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02565)

Answer (score 1):

The pre-print is really badly written, not stating what $\Omega$ is. Anyway it's easy to get the idea. $\Omega$ represent a surface which is supposedly the camera receiver. The projection is a map that goes from the 3D space to the camera receiver. The back-projection is aimed to reconstruct the projected 3D-space from the received image, so it is a map from $\Omega \times R$ (here every point of the surface $\Omega$ is linked to a one-dimensional ray) to the ordinary 3D.

What probably is disturbing is $\Omega \times R$. Probably in the author's mind this notation is a way of saying that for every point of the camera receiver $\Omega$ you have a line or ray of possible position $R$ that could have been the source of the received pixel.

This it would not be what I would have done, but if the authors choosed this set up they probably have a reason for that.

Comment: Thanks Daco! Yes I think that is the conclusion I came to as well - I think that the $\Omega$ is a 2D vector, (position on the camera image), and $R$ is a "depth" value. Only thing remaining, is to understand the nomenclature of $\Omega  \ x \ R$ - what does the 'x' mean in this context? Cross product?...